ROS2 rqt C++ plugin, undefined symbol from qt_gui_cpp
I am trying to port a Noetic C++ rqt plugin to ROS2. I did not find any tutorial or help, except question 103235 here (Where can I find an example of a C++ ROS 2 rqt plugin?). It led me to look at image_view (https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_image_view), which may be the only C++ rqt plugin ported to ROS2.
While it took me about 10 days to get Noetic plugin to compile, it was quite easy for ROS2 (about an hour). Of course, the resulting library did not work but, at least, it gave an error message on the contrary of Noetic. What I have is:
RosPluginlibPluginProvider::load_explicit_type(RobotVel2D) could not load library 
(Failed to load library .../Ros2/install/rqt_robot_vel2d/lib/rqt_robot_vel2d/librqt_robot_vel2d.so. 
Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, 
and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. 
Error string: Could not load library LoadLibrary error: 
.../Ros2/install/rqt_robot_vel2d/lib/rqt_robot_vel2d/librqt_robot_vel2d.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZNK10qt_gui_cpp6Plugin10metaObjectEv, 
at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcutils-1.1.5/src/shared_library.c:84)

I do not understand the problem, as I declared qt_gui_cpp to be needed both at build and exec in package.xml.  And, of course, an internet search did not returned anything usable.
Does anyone have an idea of the origin of this problem?
EDIT - As asked, here is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(rqt_robot_vel2d)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(qt_gui_cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rqt_gui_cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)

# to generate the moc files
qt5_wrap_cpp(${PROJECT_NAME}_MOCS
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/plugin.hpp
  )

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  src/plugin.cpp
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MOCS}
  )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${rclcpp_TARGETS}
  ${qt_gui_cpp_TARGETS}
  ${rqt_gui_cpp_TARGETS}
  Qt5::Widgets
  )

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin/${PROJECT_NAME}
#  INCLUDES DESTINATION include   # not needed !?!
  )

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
  )

install(FILES plugin.xml
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
  )

# for RQT to find the new plugin
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(rqt_gui "plugin.xml")

# Export old-style CMake variables
ament_export_include_directories("include/${PROJECT_NAME}")
ament_export_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Export new-style CMake variables
ament_export_targets(${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()

The file package.xml is shorter:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>rqt_robot_vel2d</name>
  <version>1.1.0</version>

  <description>
    This C++ GUI plugin allows to ...
  </description>

  <maintainer email="Alexis.Scheuer@loria.fr">Alexis Scheuer</maintainer>
  <author>Alexis Scheuer</author>

  <license>GPLv3</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  
  <build_depend>qtbase5-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rqt_gui</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rqt_gui_cpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>qt_gui_cpp</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rqt_gui</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rqt_gui_cpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>qt_gui_cpp</exec_depend>
  
  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
    <rqt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml"/>
  </export>

</package>

And plugin.xml is the shortest of the three:
<library path="rqt_robot_vel2d">
  <class name="RobotVel2D" type="rqt_robot_vel2d::Plugin"
     base_class_type="rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin">>
    <description>
      A C++ GUI plugin to ...
    </description>
    <qtgui>
      <group>
        <label>Robot Tools</label>
        <icon type="theme">folder</icon>
        <statustip>Plugins related to robot tools.</statustip>
      </group>
      <label>Robot 2D Velocity Control Visualisation</label>
      <icon type="theme">utilities-system-monitor</icon>
      <statustip>Shows odometry state and /cmd_vel data, and publishes robot's control in /cmd_acc topic.</statustip>
    </qtgui>
  </class>
</library>

This is not a problem with rqt or my ROS2 installation or configuration, as I have been able to compile and start the plugin rqt_image_view from its foxy source.  But I cannot see what is missing in the files given above.
EDIT 2 - According to ldd (ldd -r install/rqt_robot_vel2d/lib/rqt_robot_vel2d/librqt_robot_vel2d.so), my plugin contains 18 undefined symbols: 9 from qt_gui_cpp, 8 from class_loader and 1 from console_bridge.
Surprisingly, the plugin I compiled from rqt_image_view source has also undefined symbols from rclcpp, class_loader and console_bridge, but none from qt_gui_cpp.
I guess the problem comes from there. But I still can't see how to solve it...

Please share the CMakelists.txt, package.xml & pulgin.xml files.

Hello.
After a long pause (no holidays, just working on another project), I found the solution:  I don't know why I used ${*_TARGETS} in the target_link_libraries(...) part of CMakeLists.txt.  It simply had to be replaced by ${*_LIBRARIES} for the library to be OK and the plugin to loaded in rqt.
